# Not able to retrieve data from mobile data using bluemix

Tags: mobile, ibm-cloud, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to retrieve data from mobile data services using bluemix.

The code that I am using is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',//POST
    url: 'https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net:443/data/rest/v1/apps/c3b20173-b6a4-42d0-b543-93da13c1953e/objects?classname=Report&start=0&num=0',
    headers: {"IBM-Application-Secret": "2fc3aa67db1ab71a80f4f38aa1770ff802120848"},
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success : getData,
    error : throwError
})
function getData(data)
{ 
    console.log('GOT REPORT' + JSON.stringify(data));
}

function throwError(data)
{ 
    /*var query = Bluemixdata.Query.ofType("Report");
    query.find({Severity: "SEV 4"});
    console.log('Pallavi'+ JSON.stringify(query));*/
    console.log('GOT REPORTError' + JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

but on executing the control is moving to `throwError` method somehow may be its not hitting the URL.
Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong. Want to acknowledge that I am getting data through bluemix console and via postman but not able to retrieve using code.

Even tried to retrieve data using `Bluemixdata.Query.ofType("Report");` but getting `IBMBluemix not defined` error message that should be thrown as `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Bluemix/IBMBluemix.js"></script>` is already defined in `index.html` above all the below given js

```
LogCat Console Output:
08-13 14:36:21.993: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(21658): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/Bluemix/cordova_plugins.js
08-13 14:36:22.343: I/chromium(21658): [INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "calling bluemix initialize with values----------------", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/Services.js (10)
08-13 14:36:22.423: I/chromium(21658): [INFO:CONSOLE(13)] "----  IBM Bluemix Initializing ------", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/Services.js (13)
08-13 14:36:22.433: I/chromium(21658): [INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "HiPal", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/Services.js (16)
08-13 14:36:22.433: I/chromium(21658): [INFO:CONSOLE(17)] "GOT A PERSON ----[object Object]", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/Services.js (17)
08-13 14:36:22.453: I/chromium(21658): [INFO:CONSOLE(36)] "GOT REPORTError{"statusText":"Not Found","status":404,"response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null}", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/BarChart.js (36)
```

Comment: Hi Pallavi, 
are you sure the source code is committed/deployed to the Android App on the phone?
The log should contain rows not showed in your log (at least according to your source code you may have a line containing the word 'Pallavi') so maybe the source code is not updated and it is using an old url.
I have just tried your rest API and it is working fine so there is no reason it is not working in your webview.

Comment: Thanks, yes the source that I have pasted here its an updated one wrt to logs but it doesn't matter as I just added 1 more console.log but again I am getting same error You said my service is working at your end but its not working for me So wondering what I have missed. It would be grateful if you can help me in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are using jQuery.ajax to formulate your REST request? I suspect there is something wrong with the way you are configuring the request.

If you are going to use our hybrid SDK, you can use the APIs we provide, located [here](http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/hybrid#data-operations) to accomplish the same thing.

I also notice that the Bluemix Cordova plugin is having some problems. Try removing your android platform from your cordova project and re-add it. You can try the same with the plugins.

Also, I recommend checking out the sample [bluemixcordovadata](https://hub.jazz.net/project/ldeluca/bluemixcordovadata/overview) for more detailed usages and general help.

**Warning**: Please avoid pasting your app secret since this is a public forum.